# BinarySearchTree searching speed efficiency

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;


public class BSTSearchTimer {

int [] n = {10000, 50000, 100000, 250000};
Random rand = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    BSTSearchTimer timer = new BSTSearchTimer();
    timer.runBSTSearchTimer();

}

public void runBSTSearchTimer() throws IOException{
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter("tree2.csv"));
    int reps = 10000; // the number of searches that we will do on the tree


    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
        BinarySearchTree<Long> longBST = new BinarySearchTree<Long>();
        boolean success = true;

        int numOfElements = n[i];

        while (longBST.size() < numOfElements){

                success = longBST.add(rand.nextLong());
                while (!success){ // should keep attempting to add values until success is true
                    success = longBST.add(rand.nextLong());
            }

        }

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); // start the timer for searching

        for ( int j = 0; j < reps; j++){ // search rep times
            longBST.find(rand.nextLong());
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis(); // end timer for searching tree

        double time = end-start;

        System.out.printf("%d, %f\n", longBST.size(), time);
        out.printf("%d, %f\n", n[i], time);

    }
    out.close();
}
}
```

When I run this program it is supposed to be making 4 different sized trees: 10000, 50000, 100000, 250000. I know that the speed efficiency on searching BSTs is supposed to be O(Log n) but I am getting these numbers:

when doing 10,000 searches I get these numbers: (first column is the size of the tree, the second is the time it took to do the search)

```
10000, 9.000000
50000, 3.000000
100000, 4.000000
```

when doing 100,000 searches:

```
10000, 41.000000
50000, 31.000000
100000, 40.000000
250000, 74.000000
```

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're seeing the effect of "misses". Since you're just searching for random numbers, numbers that aren't in the tree will take a lot longer than number that are.

Also, the efficiency of a binary search tree is O(h), where h is the height of the tree. [Red-Black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) and [AVL trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) guarantee that they will be constructed with a height of O(log n), but randomly constructed trees could easily end up with a height close to O(n).

Comment: That actually makes sense. I understand it now. Thanks for the tip. I was really wondering why this code was producing what I thought were random numbers. But the fact that i'm searching for random numbers could result in a lot of different outputs. Thanks!